# "onclick" not working in my popup button (MapoboxGL)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mapbox

I'm trying to add a button inside a marker popup in mapbox gl but, when I click on it, it doesn't work. I'm using ReactJS and the method I want to call with the button is:

```js
    handleConfirm() {
      history.push("/");
      window.location.reload(false);
    }
```

I create the button this way:

```js
var description =`<a type="button" class= 'btn btn-info' id='prova' onclick="handleConfirm">Confirm</a>`         

var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup().setHTML(description);

var marker = new mapboxgl
            .Marker({color:"green"})
            .setLngLat([veicolo.longitudine, veicolo.latitudine])  
            .addTo(map)
            .setPopup(popup);
```

Does anyone know why 'onclick' does not work?

Comment: What exactly not working ?, you are using history.push that redirect the page and below after that code does not make any sense. You should provide more details.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I doubt the push method exists for the history object.  https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/History_API could might help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered the similar issue and I found this solution somewhere in their documentation or in some knowledge sharing group:

```
let popupElem = new mapboxgl.Popup()
  .setLngLat(coordinates)
  .setHTML(description)
  .addTo(map);

// Click event on popupElement
popupElem.getElement().addEventListener('click', () => {
  // your logic here
});
```